# Comic book story from 1960s: Man repairs door and is transported to another dimension?

Tags: story-identification, comics, parallel-universe

Cliched henpecked husband bugged by wife to fix door in basement (iirc, maybe not basement) and he finds, no kidding, that the door leads to another world where, with the hammer, he defends a princess of this world and becomes royalty when she marries him.

Even by 1960s I think we already in overly-explored territory -- it is the broken door as a modality that is the unusual (if implausible and uninteresting) aspect. I believe the portal already existed -- his fixing the door was not what caused it.

As often happens in interdimensional stories, time is much faster in the other dimension. The man is able to move back and forth between Earth and this new place. I think he decides to stay finally and meanwhile back at home, his wife mutters something about doing the job right need to do it yourself and fixes the door which traps the man who, despite his decision, encounters the thugs who he had fought off and when he tries to escape he finds the portal now closed -- presumably he is then killed in a world where even being a princess or married to one does not seem to count for much in terms of defense from violent subjects.